# Magento 2 : Default filter on sales admin order grid

Tags: magento2, product, order-grid, msi

I need to create a filter on sales admin order grid that only shows the orders that contain products from a specific source.

I found questions that sort of answered this for Magento 1 but not for Magento 2. Most of the solutions add a custom column to the grid and filter on that.

I need this filter to be executed on page load. If the order contains products from source A, the admin should not be able to see orders for products from source B in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

how do you see this functionality working? 
As you don't have direct Relationship between Order and Sources. What we have is Order to a Stock relationship (based on the website where this order has been placed).

What we will have are Shipments (created in the scope of order fulfillment) assigned to a particular source. 
So, we introduce Order to Source linkage via Shipping process

Comment: The products that are part of the order have a direct relation with the source. From the order id, I should be able to find out which products are part of the order and if it is not from source X, I don't want to show that order in the list.
If not, how can I create a default filter that would show orders for a particular website?

Comment: "The products that are part of the order have a direct relation with the source" - that's not exactly right. Because this relation appears only for those orders for which we have Shipment created because the Shipment process establishes this relation.  Before that - the system does not have a clue which source would be used for fulfillment. "how can I create a default filter that would show orders for a particular website?" - This data already shown on Order grid in "Purchase Point" column - if you need to do it programmatically use - \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface::getList

Comment: I do need to do it programmatically but I am very new to Magento and don't really know how to do this such that the moment the orders grid is loaded, it only shows orders from a particular purchase point. Can you please help me with the starter code. Thanks!